# accessing members of structure with sizeof

Tags: c, data-structures, sizeof

I've got this code, which I don't understand why it doesn't compile:

```
typedef struct 
{
  uint32_t serial_number;
  uint32_t ieee_address[6];
} FACTORY_CONFIG; 

...
// Unlock flash (only the portion we write on)
    error = FLASHD_Unlock ( writeaddress, writeaddress + sizeof ( FACTORY_CONFIG.serial_number ), 0, 0 );
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> Error[Pe018]: expected a ")"

When I change the

> FACTORY_CONFIG.serial_number

to

> FACTORY_CONFIG

, it compiles and everything works. I'm not sure, can I check the size of a type inside a structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just access members of types in C like that. You can, however, take `sizeof` from actual objects. And since `sizeof` is a compile-time construct, these objects don't even have to be valid. So the following will work:

```
sizeof(((FACTORY_CONFIG *)0)->serial_number)
```

If you use this a lot, or just for readability, you could make a macro out of it.

Comment: It works because `sizeof` can compute size of objects by inferring their types at compile time. Given a pointer f to FOO, f->member   is a member, and the NULL pointer (0) can also be used to avoid declaring a temporary pointer.

Comment: -1 There is an `offsetoff` macro in the standard, exactly for this purpose. This takes into account all padding issues and is portable. Don't teach people such hackery.

Comment: @JensGustedt: how does offsetof help here to just find out the size of the struct member?

Comment: @EliBendersky, he is not just using `sizeof` but adding this to a pointer. I read it that it in reality is supposed to give the address of the `ieee_address` member. Please see my answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt: my answer is a general one to the question in his title and final sentence. I did not try to second-guess his original intention

Comment: Then perhaps provide an answer that doesn't give undefined behavior? Up my knowledge there is none.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the object first. The struct you are creating is only a type. 
Do like this:

```
sizeof (((FACTORY_CONFIG *)0)->serial_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want, ist to interpret your `writeaddress` as if it were pointing to an object of your `struct` and then access the address of the `ieee_address` member.

The way such things are meant to be done in C is

```
((FACTORY_CONFIG*)writeaddress)->ieee_address
```

that's it.

The method you were using is very dangerous because you don't know how your compiler will layout the `struct` in memory. If you have to, there is the `offsetof` macro to get the exact postion of a field.

BTW, having type alias in all caps is against common coding style and against everybody's habits. Usually all caps names are reserved for macros.